# Meaning of the word "as" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here it goes:

> But the Dutch language as spoken by the Boers was now seen as a distinct language called Africaans.

Does *as* mean *because* there? To me it seems it was used to mean *the* *Dutch language that is spoken*..., but it seems to be an ungrammatical use of *as*. It was in this [video](https://youtu.be/LU6dL9FMeIU). It is at around 2 minute and 23 second.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means "in the way that" or "in the manner of", so it's "the Dutch language *in the way that it was* spoken by the Boers...".  [See definition 5 or 6 here.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/as)  *As* has a lot of meanings!

Answer (score 2):

+1 to stangdon but let's approach the question from another angle too.

The passive construction **the language as spoken by the Boers** if inverted to active voice would be **the language as Boers speak|spoke it**.

The Dutch language, as Boers spoke it, was now seen [i.e. now was regarded]  as a distinct language [i.e. separate  and sufficiently different from the language spoken  by the Dutch, as a language that had embarked on a different journey of development].

I can see where you might conclude that **as** means "because" there. But the mere fact that a different group is speaking a language is not sufficient grounds to consider what comes out of their mouths a different language. That other group must be speaking the language *in a different way*.

> An omelet *as prepared by an Italian chef* would be rather dryer than
>   how my Irish mom would make it.